# storing the json data for options of a select tag, in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Good day to you all

I am retrieving the options for my select tag in json format and populating the select tag using this

```
var mySelect = $('#'+select_id)
    $.each(response, function(key,val){
    $('<option/>',{
        value : key
    })
    .text(val)
    .appendTo(mySelect);
    });
```

Which works fine, but i want to store the html string generated out of the conversion from the json array into a variable, instead of appending it to the select tag. How can i do that?

Comment: I would push your html strings onto a new array, and then join them together when you write them to the DOM.

Comment: Do I understand you correct? You want to get the RAW html from mySelect?

Comment: exactly, thats what i want to do. Get the RAW HTML, of the option tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with `jQuery.map`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

```
var result = $.map(response, function(key,val){
    return "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>";
}).join('');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DPZGR/